# Unable to send email using mailx in Light ubuntu vmware

Tags: vmware, lubuntu, mailx

I am getting the following error while trying to send an email using mailx

command used:

```
uuencode Final_report.html $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")_report.html |mailx -s "Test of monthly report from ${HOSTNAME}" xxxx@gmail.com`
```

mailq output:

```
4D21F787       1121 Mon Jun 22 01:15:31  linux@linux-virtual-machine
(connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.219.27]:25: Connection refused)                     xxxx@gmail.com`
```

I am using light ubuntu in vmware workstation 10. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Something is blocking your connection to GMail's SMTP servers. It could be your ISP probably blocking port 25, or some (misconfigured?) firewall of yours.

Try:

```
telnet smtp.googlemail.com 25
```

Do you get a response like this?

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP w11sm34648261wjr.48 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to authenticate your session with GMail to send. [This link](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/423310-Using-mailx-to-send-mail-to-Gmail?s=d6ac486ad5cd82171d61b660fd52eed6&p=2049932#post2049932) provides the info about how to configure this.

Your command will look something like :

`uuencode Final_report.html $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")_report.html |mailx -s "Test of monthly report from ${HOSTNAME}" -S smtp-use-starttls -S ssl-verify=ignore -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp=smtp.gmail.com:587 -S from=<yourself@gmail.com> -S smtp-auth-user=<yourself@gmail.com> -S smtp-auth-password=<yourpass> xxxx@gmail.com`

Comment: Please elaborate more about the answer. Don't just enter link. Otherwise write in comments.

Comment: Sorry, elaborated :)